# Why 360 images look bigger/closer on Oculus Quest 2?

Tags: aframe, oculusquest, 360-panorama

I'm building a virtual tour app with A-Frame. Equirectangular/360 images look ok on PC and smartphone, but on Oculus Quest 2 they appear to be closer/bigger, which completely kills the immersion.

Couldn't try in a different headset, only with Oculus Quest 2 using the Oculus Browser.
Tried different fov, far, near settings, but it is not configurable in VR headsets.

There is any way to solve this?